# Add multiple drawables inside EditText

Tags: android

I need to insert more than one drawable in the end of `EditText`.

I've inserted on using `drawableRight`, but how can I add one more in the right end.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try using [layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

```
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <!-- your first drawable -->
    </item>
    <item>
        <!-- your second drawable -->
    </item>
    <item>
        <!-- your third drawable -->
    </item>
    ....
</layer-list>
```

Docs about `layer-list` says:

> A LayerDrawable is a drawable object that manages an array of other
>   drawables. Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the
>   list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top.
>
> Each drawable is represented by an  element inside a single
>    element.

Comment: thanks, and how can I make those drawables clickable & add space between items, currently they are overlapping

Comment: @reiley Use `bottom`, `top`, `right`, `left` attributes of `item` element to set offsets

Comment: @reiley please refer to [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

what about spannables:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("test");
Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
yourEditText.setText(ss);
```

you can play with the margins...